# PHP fails to parse this JSON string - what's wrong?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$b = '{
    "encoding" : "UTF-8",    
    "plug-ins" : [
        "python",
        "c++",
        "ruby"
        ],
    "indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space" = true }
}';

print "\n\n\n=================================\n";
$barr = json_decode($b, true);
print_r($barr);

?>
```

This prints nothing on the console. Is tehre something wrong with the JSON format above? - or am I missing a trick?

Comment: could it be `"use_space" = true` = to : ?

Comment: Ah, ok I can see the problem with: "use_space" = true }

Comment: when everthing in php then why using console??

Comment: @diEcho: Hmmm, you are jumping to conclusions a bit there aren't you?. Who said everything was in PHP?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your JSON isn't valid. [Check out here.](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

This:

```
"use_space" = true
```

Must be:

```
"use_space" : true
```

Answer (score 3):

The `indent` property has an error in its `use_space` property:

```
"indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space" = true }
```

The equal should be a colon.

```
"indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space" : true }
```

Comment: Note to self: I MUST check for obvious errors before asking for help on SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = '{
    "encoding" : "UTF-8",    
    "plug-ins" : [
        "python",
        "c++",
        "ruby"
        ],
    "indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space" : true }
}';

print "\n\n\n=================================\n";
$barr = json_decode($b, true);
print_r($barr);
```

?>